Why does getch() interrupt my display() method?
I'm trying to write 2048 game (a simple puzzle game, you can find it easily online if you don't know it) in python and I've run into a problem.
When I use input() to get user input everything works great but when I use getch() the current_board.display() method gets interrupted somehow and prints only 3 upper rows when i first run the program, and after every move it prints the last row of the previous state of the board at the top, and 3 upper rows of the current state under it.
Please ignore all other issues with the code
main.py:
from classes import *
from os import system
import msvcrt

current_board = Board(grid_init())

while True:
    system("cls")
    current_board.display()
    #current_board.move(input())
    current_board.move(msvcrt.getch().decode("ASCII"))

classes.py:
import random
import copy


class Board:
    def __init__(self, grid):
        self.__grid = grid

    def display(self):
        for row in range(4):
            print("\n")
            for col in range(4):
                print(self.__grid[row][col], end = "     ")

    def move(self, dir):
        if dir == "w":
            row_range = [0, 3, 1]
            col_range = [0, 4, 1]
            row_shift = 1
            col_shift = 0
        elif dir == "a":
            row_range = [0, 4, 1]
            col_range = [0, 3, 1]
            row_shift = 0
            col_shift = 1
        elif dir == "s":
            row_range = [3, 0, -1]
            col_range = [3, -1, -1]
            row_shift = -1
            col_shift = 0
        elif dir == "d":
            row_range = [3, -1, -1]
            col_range = [3, 0, -1]
            row_shift = 0
            col_shift = -1
        else:
            print(dir)
        prev_grid = []
        while prev_grid != self.__grid:
            prev_grid = copy.deepcopy(self.__grid)
            for row in range(row_range[0], row_range[1], row_range[2]):
                for col in range(col_range[0], col_range[1], col_range[2]):
                    if self.__grid[row][col] == 0:
                        self.__grid[row][col] = self.__grid[row+row_shift][col+col_shift]
                        self.__grid[row+row_shift][col+col_shift] = 0
                    elif self.__grid[row][col] == self.__grid[row+row_shift][col+col_shift]:
                        self.__grid[row][col] *= 2
                        self.__grid[row+row_shift][col+col_shift] = 0

def grid_init():
    grid = [[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
    x1 = random.randint(0, 3)
    y1 = random.randint(0, 3)
    x2 = x1
    y2 = y1
    while x1 == x2 and y1 == y2:
        x2 = random.randint(0, 3)
        y2 = random.randint(0, 3)
    for row in range(4):
        for col in range(4):
            if (row == x1 and col == y1) or (row == x2 and col == y2):
                grid[row][col] = 1
    return grid

I tried assigning getch() to a variable and passing it to the move() method but it didn't solve the problem.

The problem here is that input is a part of Python and is integrated with the Python I/O system, but msvcrt.getch is outside of Python, so it didn't know it was supposed to flush the buffered output.
What you need to do is make sure the output is flushed before you call getch.
sys.stdout.flush()
# or
print('',end='',flush=True)

You might consider whether msvcrt.getch is really necessary here.  Remember that it is Windows-only.  There are other ways to achieve your goal that will remain cross-platform.
